# Cannot put a Nestedlist on a tab panel sencha touch, only render the tittle

Tags: extjs, touch, nested-lists, tabpanel

Hi have been wandering around with simplified code and trying to fit the mvc pattern but cant get it to works! can anyone give me a hand? thanks!
I have been comparing with others codes and seems pretty standart to this.

app.js

```
Ext.application({
name: 'flop',

requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox'
],

views: [ 'Main' , 'capitulos' ],
models: [ 'h1_1model' ],
stores: [ 'h1_1store' ],

launch: function() {
 Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();
 Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('flop.view.Main'))     
}});
```

Main.js

```
Ext.define('flop.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
fullscreen: true,
config:
{    

items: [
        {
         title: 'datos'

        },
        {
         xtype: 'capitulos',
         title: 'se'
         },
        {
         title: 'configs'
        }
       ]
}});
```

capitulos.js

```
Ext.define('flop.view.capitulos', {
extend: 'Ext.NestedList',
xtype: 'capitulos',
store: 'h1_1store'});
```

h1_1store.js

```
Ext.define('flop.store.h1_1store', {
 extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
 model: 'flop.model.h1_1model',
        defaultRootProperty: 'items',
        root: {
            items: [
                {
                    text: 'Drinks',
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: 'Water',
                            items: [
                                { text: 'Still', leaf: true },
                                { text: 'Sparkling', leaf: true }
                            ]
                        },
                        { text: 'Soda', leaf: true }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text: 'Snacks',
                    items: [
                        { text: 'Nuts', leaf: true },
                        { text: 'Pretzels', leaf: true },
                        { text: 'Wasabi Peas', leaf: true  }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }});
```

h1_1model.js

```
Ext.define('flop.model.h1_1model', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        config: {
            fields: ['text']
        }});
```